# Spring doesn't use my Conerverter. Why?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jodatime

I have custom Converter:

```
public class DateTimeConverter implements Converter<String, DateTime> {

    private static final String DEFAULT_DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    private DateTimeFormatter formatter;

    private String datePattern = DEFAULT_DATE_PATTERN;

    public String getDatePattern() {
        return datePattern;
    }

    @Autowired(required = false)
    public void setDatePattern(String datePattern) {
        this.datePattern = datePattern;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(datePattern);
    }

    @Override
    public DateTime convert(String source) {
        if (source == null) return new DateTime();
        return formatter.parseDateTime(source);
    }
}
```

And field in JavaBean:

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "dateandtime")
private DateTime dateAndTime;
```

I registered my converter in setting:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>
<bean id="conversionService"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.myapp.util.DateTimeConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I got this exception:

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.joda.time.DateTime' for property 'dateAndTime'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.joda.time.DateTime] for property 'dateAndTime': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/resources/spring/business-config.xml")
public class JdbcTransactionRepositoryImplTest extends TestCase {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JdbcTransactionRepositoryImplTest.class);

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

private JdbcTransactionRepositoryImpl transactionRepository;

@Before
public void setup() {
    transactionRepository = new JdbcTransactionRepositoryImpl((DataSource)         context.getBean("dataSource"));
}

@Test
public void testFindById() throws Exception {
    Transaction tr1 = transactionRepository.findById(1);
    assertEquals(new Long(1L), tr1.getId());
}
```

But, in this case:

```
@Test
public void testFindById() throws Exception {
    ConversionService conversionService = (ConversionService) context.getBean("conversionService");
    assertTrue(conversionService.canConvert(String.class, DateTime.class));
```

Build success!

I don't understand: why? 
Thank you for any help

Comment: When do you get the exception? Post the code that triggers it.

Comment: When I launch tests I get the exception.

Comment: Show us the test class then...

Comment: @john812 is ConversionService registered in `business-config.xml`? Can you autowire your `DateTimeConverter` in the test?

Comment: Yes, ConversionService is registered in business-config.xml and I can autowire my converter and conversionService (annotation @Autowired)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create your own converter or register conversion service - if Joda-Time is in project's classpath, [Spring will automagically enable conversions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable) through [`@DateTimeFormat`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) annotation (`<mvc:annotation-driven />` is required).

So what you need is just:

```
@NotNull
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
private DateTime dateAndTime;
```

Comment: You are 100% right. However it is still quite a mystery why the custom converter does not work.

Comment: @PavelHoral It's typical [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) IMO.

Comment: Might be, but that was not the point of my comment. The configuration seems completely valid and yet, it is not working.